# Accessing array values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Please can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? I am trying to retrieve all the data in the array below in PHP and I am having problems doing this. Here is the example:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www.example.com/';

if (!$fp = fopen($url, 'r')) {
    trigger_error("Unable to open URL ($url)", E_USER_ERROR);
}

$meta = stream_get_meta_data($fp);

print_r($meta);

foreach($meta as $key=>$value) {
    echo '<br>'.$value;

}

fclose($fp);

?>
```

The foreach loop above permit me to loop through and retrieve all the data in the array, but my questions are:

1. How can I retrieve only the value http of `[wrapper_type]` and other
   values independently?
2. How can I retrieve only one value of
   `[wrapper_data] => Array` without retrieving all the values together?
3. What is the index number or value to access these data?

Comment: Ummm... `echo $meta['wrapper_type'];`

Comment: _What is the index number or value to access these data?_ - this questions is unclear.

Comment: `wrapper_data` array will be variable as it is based on the headers and is in the order that the headers were received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty basic stuff; you may want to do some reading up on PHP basics before progressing further. Nevertheless...

> How can I retrieve only the value http of [wrapper_type] and other values independently?

```
$type = $meta["wrapper_type"];
echo $type;
```

> How can I retrieve only one value of [wrapper_data] => Array without retrieving all the values together?

```
$the_fourth_header = $meta["wrapper_data"][4];
echo $the_fourth_header;
```

Comment: Hi Miken, thanks for taking the time to respond. I appreciate it. I will do as you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: I already voted up your response and it says I need to earn a total of 15 reputation before the vote would appear. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I retrieve only the value http of [wrapper_type]

Just with `$meta['wrapper_data']`

> How can I retrieve only one value of [wrapper_data]

The same, Array elements can be accessed using the array[key] syntax: `$meta['wrapper_data'][0]`, `$meta['wrapper_data'][1]`, ...

Comment: Hi Federico, thanks for the feedback. I appreciate it. I got it completely.

Answer (score -1):

just use 'wrapper_type' index in your array($meta).

```
$type = $meta["wrapper_type"];
echo $type;
```